# Potentiometer controlled current regulation

Tags: current, dc

new one here.

Thing is this; 
I have an electromagnet (or a solenoid as I prefer to call it). When it gets energized the plunger inside is pushed out to a certain length (goes back to its original position thanks to a spring). It is supposed to work on 12V DC. It has two leads and the resistance between them is 0.9 Ohm. Assuming the voltage would be constant, max current it can draw would be 13,3 Amps. I need to be able to control how far the plunger can get pushed out. I am led to believe that with constant voltage this can be achieved by varying (limiting?) current to the solenoid.

The question: 
How would such a circuit look like? Is it doable with LM317 or something similar (LM350?)? Would a thyristor or a transistor be of any use? I'm really newbie to electronics, but willing to learn. Is there even a proper 'name' to the kind of circuit I am looking for?

P.S. I know current limiting can be achieved by increasing resistance, like with a potentiometer, but the pot might become dangerously hot, right?

Or am I talking rubbish ...

Someone please enlighten me... Thx in advance.

Comment: one of those cheap PMDC motor controllers would probably work for you, get one good for at-least  15A and 15V and put a 15A (or more) schottky diode parallel with the coil.

Comment: You might want to test your theory about extension vs current with a lab supply before investing a lot of time or money in building a controller.

Comment: I totally agree with Spehro Pefhany.. I don't think you will be able to linearly control the plunger extension with proportional current control. Unlikely with pwm too... This is because the magnetic force on the plunger core will vary significantly depending on its positions inside of the solenoid.

Answer (score 1):

> It has two leads and the resistance between them is 0.9 Ohm. Assuming the voltage would be constant, max current it can draw would be 13,3 Amps.

Correct.

> I need to be able to control how far the plunger can get pushed out. I am led to believe that with constant voltage this can be achieved by varying (limiting?) current to the solenoid.

Slightly garbled. Voltage and current are related as dictated by Ohm's Law. If you can reduce either one the other will reduce too.

> Is it doable with LM317 or something similar (LM350?)?

13 A is high current and any linear regulator will have to dissipate all the power dropped in the regulator. e.g. If the current is 10 A at around 9 V out then there will be 3 V across the regulator at 10 A so \$ P = VI = 3 \cdot 10 = 30~W \$ heat dissipation requiring a large heatsink.

> Would a thyristor or a transistor be of any use?

Thyristors are good for AC. Once triggered they remain on until the current through them falls to zero so in your circuit the thyristor would remain on until something else switched it off. You might as well use the something else to switch it on as well.

If, however, you wish to control from a transformer a triac (a bi-directional thyristor) control circuit is usually quite simple. Power is adjusted by delaying the turn-on of the AC waveform.

[image]

*Figure 1. Varying the turn-on point of the triac allows variation of voltage or current from almost 100% to 0%.*

Note that highly inductive loads such as solenoids require special consideration for reliable operation.

> Is there even a proper 'name' to the kind of circuit I am looking for?

Read up on pulse-width modulation (PWM). This technique gives pulses of energy to the device being controlled (motor, lamp, LED, etc.) with the pulse width determining the average voltage / current delivered. The pulse frequency is chosen to be high enough that the device operates smoothly. e.g., the motor doesn't vibrate or the lamps don't noticeably flicker.

[image]

*Figure 2. PWM power control showing 75% - 25% - 75% - 0% power sequence.*

> I know current limiting can be achieved by increasing resistance, like with a potentiometer, but the pot might become dangerously hot, right?

Correct. High powered "rheostats" were used in theatre lighting, electric tram traction control and probably by Flash Gordon but have mostly been replaced by electronic control due to increased efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you need is a timed pulse and a switch transistor.

A MOSFET switch, driven from a '555 timer, connects 12V to your solenoid.
The current rises according to

V = 12V = L dI/dt

and at some time when the plunger is at the right extension,
the '555 turns the power off, .
Current in the inductor doesn't just turn off, when dI/dt goes from
positive to negative, it creates negative voltage (see above equation)
so you'll want to quench that with a diode across the inductor.